# How to fix shift/reduce problem between tab and space

Tags: c, parsing, compilation, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to write a minipython compiler, and as we know, Python works with spaces to define a block.  In my situation, I defined the block as exactly 4 spaces, but when I want to create a block with multiple lines it tells that there is a shift/reduce conflict.  I guess I know where the problem is; it doesn't know to treat the second line as space or tab, but I am not sure, so here is my code:

lexical :

```
"    " {column = column + strlen(yytext); return mc_tab;}


" " {column = column + strlen(yytext);}
```

syntaxic :

```
S : INSTRUCTION S 
    | {printf("\nWINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER\n");YYACCEPT;}
;

INSTRUCTION : DECL mc_jmp | LOOP | COND | mc_jmp
;


COND : IF ELSE
;

IF : mc_if mc_opnArc COMPARISION mc_clsArc mc_dblpnt mc_jmp BEGIN_BLOCK
;

ELSE : mc_else mc_dblpnt BEGIN_BLOCK | 


BEGIN_BLOCK : mc_tab INSTRUCTION BEGIN_BLOCK |
;
```

Just to know, when I deleted the recursion in BEGIN_BLOCK, the conflict is gone.

EDIT :
and there is another problem, I guess if we solved it, then the first will be solved too.

when I write TAB in any line of code it will be treated exactly as that tab didn't exist, so the code treated the tab exactly as it treats the 4 spacements

Comment: I don't think Yacc/Bison is enough for a Python-like parse, it doesn't have enough context.

Comment: Style notes (not addressing your problem) — The layout you are using for the grammar rules is unorthodox.  Normally, the `|` for an alternative comes at the start, not the end, of the line.  It doesn't make a difference to Yacc; it does make a big difference to readers.  Normally, you put the empty option first, not at the end as in your `ELSE` rule, where you have a trailing `|` on one line and a `;` on the next defining the empty alternative.  And you normally put a comment in the rule — along the lines of `/* Nothing */` or `/* Empty */`.

Comment: You've not provided enough context to make an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  You seem to have reversed the normal convention of lower-case names for non-terminals and upper-case names for token (terminals).

Comment: It is not entirely clear how your lexical analyzer works, but it should probably return a token (maybe you use `mc_tab`) for the indentation at the start of a line.  The semantic analysis will validate whether the indentation at the start of each line is the same as the previous line (in which case it is part of the current block) or whether it is less (in which case it marks the end of one or more blocks), or whether it is more (in which case it marks the start of a new block).  You'll need to do different actions based on that.  I'm not absolutely sure whether Yacc/Bison can handle that.

Comment: A shift / reduce conflict is a *parser* issue, not a lexer issue.  It's coming from Bison.

Comment: Your grammar appears to be missing a semicolon after the definition of `ELSE`.

Comment: You are using right recursion in some of your productions for `S` and `BEGIN_BLOCK`.  Although Bison understands that, you should always use *left* recursion with Bison (and yacc).

Comment: It is possible to deal with python syntax in lex/yacc, but non trivial.  You need to have your lexer track the amount of indentation on each line with a small stack to track previous indent levels and have it return INDENT and UNINDENT tokens as appropriate.  You need some counters to *not* do this inside of `(`..`)` or `[`..`]` or other quoted contexts, and you also want to ignore blank lines (or lines that are just comments)

Comment: @john: yacc (as standardised by Posix) does not require rules to be terminated with semicolons, and as far as I know that was never a requirement. Python, on the other hand, does require statements to be explicitly terminated, either with a semicolon or with an unguarded newline. So the lexer must produce newline tokens. If it ignores all newlines, you'll get parsing conflicts. (Normally the lexer swallows newlines inside parenthetic constructs, but that can be done in the parser.)

Comment: @rici, yacc (and bison) allow multiple productions for the same symbol to be separated by `|` symbols, but as far as I can tell [the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html) *does* require the last one to be followed by a semicolon: "A grammar rule has the form: `A : BODY ;`".  [The bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Rules-Syntax.html) contains an equivalent specification.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: the text of the posix spec does say that, but if you look later down you will see the "linout grammar" section: "The following input to yacc yields a parser for the input to yacc. **This formal syntax takes precedence over the preceding text syntax description.**" (Emphasis added.) And that grammar clearly shows the semicolon to be optional (see the `prec` production at the end.) Also see the rationale.

Comment: Sorry, "input grammar" section. Too late to edit. Optional semicolons make yacc input files harder to parse, since the naive grammar would be LALR(2). The grammar in Posix uses a lexical hack (see C_IDENTIFIER) which is how Bison implements it. The Bison manual does not mention that semicolons are optional, both in rules and declarations, but they are.

Comment: All right, @rici, this detail is new to me.  However, I nevertheless claim that as a matter of style, it is preferable to terminate rules with semicolons as described in the specification text and demonstrated in the formal grammar presented in the spec. And especially to be consistent about use of semicolons.  I am fairly confident that the omission from the grammar presented in this question was not an intentional exercise of the freedom you point out.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in comments, shift / reduce conflicts are parser issues.  They are being reported by Bison in your case, and they are a function of your grammar (only).  If you ask it to do so via either or both of `-v` or `-r all`, Bison will produce an output file that shows you (among other things) exactly where such conflicts occur.

The grammar presented in the question is incomplete, but I made it into an input file that Bison would accept by adding section delimiters and adding a `%token` declaration for each symbol that is not otherwise defined.  I also added the semicolon that appears to have been intended after the definition of the `ELSE` symbol, before the definition of `BEGIN_BLOCK`.  Bison reported *four* shift / reduce conflicts for the result:

- when the token on top of the stack is an `IF` and the next token is an `mc_else`, it is ambiguous whether to reduce zero tokens to an `ELSE` or to shift the `mc_else` in anticipation of performing a later reduction to an `ELSE`.  This arises in part because the grammar accommodates nested conditionals, so it is a manifestation of the common issue of matching `else`s with the appropriate `if`s.
- when the tokens on top of the stack are `mc_else` `mc_dblpnt` and the next token is an `mc_tab`, it is ambiguous whether to reduce zero tokens to a `BEGIN_BLOCK` or to shift the `mc_tab` in anticipation of an `INSTRUCTION` to follow.
- when a token sequence that can be reduced to a `BEGIN_BLOCK` is required and the next token is an `mc_tab`, it is ambiguous whether to reduce zero tokens to a `BEGIN_BLOCK` or to shift the `mc_tab` in anticipation of reducing to a `BEGIN_BLOCK` via the other production for that.
- when the tokens on top of the stack are `mc_if` `mc_opnArc` `COMPARISION` `mc_clsArc` `mc_dblpnt` `mc_jmp` and the next token is an `mc_tab`, it is ambiguous whether to reduce zero tokens to a `BEGIN_BLOCK` or to shift the `mc_tab` in anticipation of an `INSTRUCTION` to follow.

A common theme emerges: empty rules are biting you hard.  Such rules are by no means the only way that a shift / reduce conflict can emerge, but I presume that you will recognize that allowing the parser to create a token out of nothing is something to be handled with considerable care.

---

The name and usage of `BEGIN_BLOCK` in particular suggest a design problem, especially in conjunction with the fact that there is no corresponding `END_BLOCK`.  Python's own parsing approach relies on the lexical analyzer to track indentation levels, and to emit synthetic `indent` *and corresponding `dedent`* tokens, as appropriate, when the indentation level changes.  Sometimes a sequence of multiple dedents must be emitted to maintain correct indent / dedent pairing.  And again, `indent`s and `dedent`s correspond to indentation level changes, not individual characters.

Making the lexer track indents and corresponding dedents allows for grammatic rules along these lines:

```
if_stmt: IF conditional_expr COLON block optional_else ;

optional_else: /* empty */
    | ELSE COLON block
;

block: INDENT stmts DEDENT ;

stmts: stmt
    | stmts stmt  /* note _left_ recursion */
;

stmt: ...

conditional_expr: ...
```

Note that the block structure is completely unambiguous -- a block begins with an `indent` and ends with a matching `dedent`.  Although it may not be immediately obvious, that takes care not only of ambiguities such as arise from your empty `BEGIN_BLOCK` productions, but also ambiguities such as arise from your rules providing for optional `else` clauses.  The latter are addressed because now the grammar allows at most one `if` with which any given `else` can pair.

You could do similar.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I started getting where the problem is, but look, here is what I want, I want to do an if-else statement and the else is optional, so I need to make an empty block right? the problem is it always reduces and does not take else as a statement, so if I knew how to do it I will be able to fix all shifts/reduce the problem, I would be thankful if you give me a hand.

Comment: @YasserAssoul, this answer does not claim that you cannot use empty productions.  It says you have to use them *carefully*, and it points out that your particular use of them is causing you trouble. It also provides an example grammar supporting an `if` statement with optional `else` (involving an empty production) that has no shift / reduce conflicts, and it discusses why the differences between this variation and yours are effective for that purpose.